# Dual monitors with displayport to HDMI

Tags: multiple-monitors, displayport

I have a Lenovo T510 laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 x64.

I can run dual monitors with my main display and internal, but not internal and displayport.

The displayport is connected to a dp to HDMI converter, which works perfectly in Windows.

In Ubuntu, when I connect the TV, the internal screen works, but the TV goes white, and the adapter gets really hot after a while. Also the screen doesn't show up in the displays menu even when I spam the detect displays button.

Also, according to Ubuntu, there are no proprietary drivers for this system. The card is a nVidia.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Although not officially supported by UBUNTU you will need to install the proprietary nvidia driver at nvidia.com if there are no detected drivers. Then i would recommend the ARANDR screen utility if the default one does not do the trick for you. But the nvidia-settings utilty should give you just about everything you need.